# Multiselect hierarchical dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have following requirement :

1. Display a drop down based on hierarchy (Parent child relationship).
2. Every node should be check-able (A checkbox in every option)
3. If we select all child nodes, then parent should be checked
       automatically or vice a versa.

For example :
Inside a drop-down I want something like this :

```
[Checkbox]Element 1
      [Checkbox]Element 1.1
      [Checkbox]Element 1.2
             [Checkbox]Element 1.2.1
             [Checkbox]Element 1.2.2
[Checkbox]Element 2
      [Checkbox]Element 2.1
      [Checkbox]Element 2.2
             [Checkbox]Element 2.2.1
             [Checkbox]Element 2.2.2
```

Kindly suggest any solution or if there is any plugin available. The hierarchy may be even more that 4-5 levels in future.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made dummy code. Hope it will help you.

Html -

```
<div class="parent">
  <input type="checkbox">1
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">1.1
    <input type="checkbox">1.2
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">1.2.1
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox">1.2.1.1
        <input type="checkbox">1.2.1.2
        <input type="checkbox">1.2.1.3
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox">1.2.2
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox">2
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">2.1
    <input type="checkbox">2.2
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery -

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var status = false;
  $(this).next().find('input').prop('checked', this.checked); 
    status = ($(this).parent().find('> input').not(':checked').length === 0);
  $(this).parent().prev().prop('checked', status);
  if(status){
        $(this).parent().prev().trigger("change");
  }
  else{
    $(this).parents().prev().prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

You can refer demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/w0trj615/1/

Comment: I was implementing the same today. I guess that's the best way to create your own. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin
[Bootstrap Treeview](http://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/)

I use it for similar cases like yours.

Comment: Good but not under a dropdown.  Checkboxes are also there in tree ,thats great but I need a dropwdown containing this.